# Complex Microsoft Graph API Query, Possible?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-entra-id

Suppose I wanted to query a list of `microsoft.graph.group` that were members of `Group A`, and I wanted to include in the result set members of those groups that were of type `microsoft.graph.user`, but only those users that are assigned to `App Role B`.

Is this possible? Can anyone get me started in that direction (I'm stumped)? Here's what I have so far:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/members/microsoft.graph.group?$expand=members($select=id,displayName)&$select=id,displayName
```

This produced the following data set (redacted of course):

```json
[
    {
        "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "displayName": "Group (52)",
        "members": [
            {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "displayName": "Marshawn Lynch"
            },
            {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "displayName": "Richard Sherman"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "displayName": "Group (542)",
        "members": [
            {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "displayName": "Kam Chancellor"
            },
            {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "displayName": "Earl Thomas"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "displayName": "Group (821)",
        "members": [
            {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "displayName": "Tyler Lockett"
            },
            {
                "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
                "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "displayName": "D.K. Metcalf"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The only thing missing is the filter on the users. Who can help?

Edit 1:

I tried the following query to apply the user filter:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/members/microsoft.graph.group?$expand=members($select=id,displayName,appRoleAssignments;$filter=type eq 'microsoft.graph.user';$expand=appRoleAssignments($select=appRoleId))&$select=id,displayName
```

Which produced the following error:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: Could not find a property named 'appRoleAssignments' on type 'microsoft.graph.directoryObject'.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2024-01-04T23:16:32",
            "request-id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "client-request-id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, it is not possible to filter (ID, display name, and app role assignments) for users in a group in a single Microsoft Graph query. You need to make different calls to get the user app role assignments like `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/appRoleAssignments/AppRoleID`

Comment: And  Microsoft Graph does not support the $filter on appRoleId check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/603125/how-to-filter-approleassignments-based-on-approlei

Answer (score 1):

I used the same query and got the results like below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/GroupAID/members/microsoft.graph.group?$expand=members($select=id,displayName)&$select=id,displayName
```

[image]

**Note** that: You can filter users and groups in one query, hence make use of different calls.

As a workaround, to retrieve only the members of the Group, make use of below query:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/GroupID/members/microsoft.graph.user?$select=id,displayName
```

[image]

> **Note**: Microsoft Graph does not support the $filter on appRoleId. Check this [**Microsoft QnA**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/603125/how-to-filter-approleassignments-based-on-approlei)  by CarlZhao-MSFT.

Hence you have to either check the user's app role assignments individually or filter it by **`resourceId`** like below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/appRoleAssignments
```

[image]

Filter by **`resourceId`**:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/appRoleAssignments?$filter=resourceId eq ResourceID
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[List appRoleAssignments granted to a user - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)